# What is an appropriate way to compare the impact properties between a plastic and a metal?

Tags: materials, plastic, aluminum

I'm currently looking at trying to compare the impact strengths between *polycarbonate* and *aluminum* to see which one performs better if made into a box and dropped. My intuition says that aluminum can absorb more energy than the polycarbonate, but to be honest I'm not exactly sure how I can prove that using a material property.

Going on MatWeb I can see that the Izod Impact, Notched (ISO) strength is 67.7 kJ/m^2 for polycarbonate. However, I'm not exactly sure what the equivalent material property might be for aluminum. Lets say we take 6061-T6 aluminum, there isn't anything really comparable to finding the kinetic energy needed to initiate fracture in polycarbonate. Does anyone know where I should start looking? Thanks.

Polycarbonate: https://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=501acbb63cbc4f748faa7490884cdbca

Aluminum:  https://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=b8d536e0b9b54bd7b69e4124d8f1d20a

Comment: Concern: Plastics become brittle as the temperature is lowered (freezing temperatures). Consider operating service temperature range.

Comment: Anther way to look at it ; aluminum will dent , polycarbonate will not ( it may fracture under high stress.)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the problem is that aluminum alloys can come with different heat treatments/thicknesses which can significantly change their impact properties. For example the following table is from the following [research gate article](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Charpy-impact-test-results-for-6061-aluminum-alloy-quenched-in-different-media_tbl4_237373581)

[image]

In the table above you may observe that the quenching media and temperature can sometimes double the Charpy impact values (Charpy is similar to Izod but is commonly used with metals).

However, only you may find other resources that mention Izod values. E.g. in [this one](https://ijcrt.org/papers/IJCRT2002182.pdf) the Izod test yields a value of 3.7 Joule for the given thickness.

One valuable resource (although outdated) is the following monograph:

https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/MONO/nbsmonograph63.pdf

Comment: Standard Izod and charpy are both 10 mm square . With thickness less than 5 mm the results are inconsistent for metals.

Comment: I'll add that Izod and Charpy test are by some considered for being "unreliable" in general. But they can serve for a qualitative comparison at least.

Comment: Three tests for a particular condition would be a good start toward reliable data.  For steels , process control prior to final heat treat is very influential.